# How to do conditional update on columns using CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, row-number

I have a table `CUST` with following layout. There are no constraints. I do see that one `ChildID` has more than one `ParentID` associated with it. (Please see the records for `ChildID = 115`)

Here is what I need -

Wherever one child has more than 1 parent, I want to update those `ParentID` and `ParentName` with the `ParentID` and `ParentName` which has max `match_per`. So in the below image, I want `ParentID` 1111 and `ParentName` LEE YOUNG WOOK to update all records where `ChildId = 115` (since the `match_per` 0.96 is maximum within the given set). In case there are two parents with equal max match_per, then I want to pick any 1 one of them.

[image: Data Layout]

I know it is possible using CTE but I don't know how to update CTE. Can anybody help?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT * FROM myCTE` try `UPDATE myCTE SET myCTE.ParentName = 'Whatever' WHERE myCTE.YourColumn = 'somethingvalue'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN match_per = 
              MAX(match_per) OVER (PARTITION BY ChildId) 
            THEN CAST(ParentId AS CHAR(10)) + ParentName 
       END AS parentDetailsForMax
FROM CUST 
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *,
        MAX(parentDetailsForMax) OVER (PARTITION BY ChildId) AS maxParentDetailsForMax
FROM CTE1
)
UPDATE CTE2
SET ParentId = CAST(LEFT(maxParentDetailsForMax,10) AS int), 
    ParentName = SUBSTRING(maxParentDetailsForMax,10,8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting both the parent id and parent name is a bit tricky.  I think the logic is easiest using `cross apply`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, p.parentId as new_parentId, p.parentName as new_parentName
             max(match_per) over (partition by childid) as max_match_per,
             count(*) over (partition by childid) as numparents
      from table t cross apply 
           (select top 1 p.*
            from table p
            where p.childid = t.childid
            order by match_per desc
           ) p
     )
update toupdate
    set parentId = new_ParentId,
        parentName = new_ParentName
    where numparents > 1;
```

As a note:  the fact that parent id and parent name are both stored in the table, potentially multiple times seems like a problem.  I would expect to look up the name, given the id, to reduce data redundancy.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for your help. I think I would go with Martin's answer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?? The first CTE will get `Max(match_per)` for each ChildID. Then, the second will use the new MaxMatchPer to find what its corresponding ParentID should be.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ChildID,MAX(match_per) AS MaxMatchPer
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY ChildID
), CTE1 AS (
    SELECT t.ParentID, c.ChildID
    FROM tbl t
    JOIN CTE c
        ON c.ChildID = t.ChildID
        AND c.MaxMatchPer = t.match_per
)
UPDATE t
SET ParentID = c.ParentID
FROM tbl t
LEFT JOIN CTE1 c
    ON c.ChildID = t.ChildID
```

Also, this is poor normalization. You should not have ParentName nor ChildName in this table.